# Reviving Game On

Tags: discussion, game-on

> [The results of badps poll produced the following times:](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/determining-the-hour-that-works-the-best-for-game-ons)
>
> ```
> Saturday 1900 - 2215 UTC
>   Sunday 1900 - 2215 UTC
> ```
>
> Visit [this](http://www.doodle.com/we852h3gcctg5ux2#table) link to have the times converted to your local time zone.

Now that we have our own [Team Fortress 2 server](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/community-team-fortress-2-server), I think it's the perfect time to revive [Game on!.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/271/se-game-on)

In terms of future Game On!, what games would you like to see included as part of our Game On! lineup? One game per answer please, that way we can easily keep track of how much support each game has.

Hopefully we will be able to revive Game On!.

Comment: The only thing about 3pm GMT/UTC is that it's 8am PDT.

Comment: @Powerlord We can change the time if we need to. I'm aware it will be difficult to find a time that works for everyone given our diverse group, which is why I mention in my meta for anyone to suggest different times if 3pm UTC  does not work for them

Comment: Ugh. Which is GMT again?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: AKA UTC, your time zone is expressed as an offset from it.  For instance, US Eastern Daylight Time is -0400 (or four hours earlier).  Which would be 11am.

Comment: I think I'm used to seeing it with a different acronym... thanks, though.

Comment: I'm often busy at that time and can't play anything particularly violent (or otherwise not child-safe) until my daughter is asleep. Locks me out of most games until UTC19:00-22:00 (or 20-23 when we move out of DST).

Comment: @DMA57361 That time range work for me. What about everyone else?

Answer (score 11):

**Minecraft adventure maps.**

Specficially these ones: [Race for wool #1](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/191908-ctmcollection-%E2%98%A0-vechs-super-hostile-series-%E2%98%A0/#AnchorRace1), [Race for wool #2](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/191908-ctmcollection-%E2%98%A0-vechs-super-hostile-series-%E2%98%A0/#AnchorRace2) or [Capture the wool](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/191908-ctmcollection-vechs-super-hostile-series/#AnchorCapture1)

These are 4-8 players and must be played from the start (no drop-ins). So would be harder to organise.

Our play-throughs of capture the wool:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4CA8A1530A02A3FC

Comment: Somebody should blog about your Game On on this map!

Comment: @IvoFlipse Way ahead of you, I've been recording the whole thing. When we finish playing I'll start posting them!

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of completeness, I'm adding **Team Fortress 2** here as well.

Comment: It might be a good idea to schedule another TF2 event a week or two from today, during the Halloween event.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>**Frozen Synapse**</strike>

---

**EDIT:**
We *(Wipqozn and I)* have decided that this would work better if played as a tournament separate from *Game On!*.
As such, we **will not** be scheduling this into *Game On!* sessions, but [a tournament is in the works](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/frozen-synapse-tournament)

Comment: And Diablo 3, prolly.

Comment: +1 for Frozen Synapse. It won't require such specific time commitments (asynchronous turn-based) so might be easier internationally, and a structured league or tournament of some kind would be kinda fun. I wonder how many players we'd have thou'.

Comment: @DMA57361 I agree with you on Frozen Synapse. Clearly GnomeSlice is a genius for suggesting it.

Comment: @RavenDreamer DIablo 3 is a good idea as well. I'm planning to buy it on release myself.

Comment: Diablo 3 is a great choice. Y'know. In 2020 when it finally releases. I'll still buy it at that point, of course...

Answer (score 7):

[**TankBall 2**](http://maidmarian.com/Tank.htm).

It's a browser based game, completely free, easily accessible, and not very intensive, so it's easy to run.  It does however, require Shockwave player (it's sort of old).

Up to four teams of any size scramble around a small island in nimble little vehicles shooting bouncing explosives at one another.  With enough people, you end up with shots flying all over the place.

Yes, it may be sort of old.  Yes, it may be a tad unpolished.  Yes, it may not look the greatest.  Yes, the controls may kind of suck.  But it sure is a lot of chaotic fun when playing in a group.

- It's free
- It's gigantically accessible
- It's easy to pick up and play
- It's fun!

[image: TankBall 2]

[image: Fustercluck]

The great part is that by using the /join # command, we could all join our own game room (there are 99 to choose from).  Maybe room 53 (SE, get it?), for example.

Comment: Great idea Gnome.

Answer (score 6):

[**League of Legends**](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/)

I've never played myself, but I know a sizable amount of our community does. When you also consider that the game is free to play, it's a prime candidate for Game On!.

The game does have three servers though, so if we do choose to play this I think the fair thing to do is to play on the server which currently has the most Gaming.SE members on it, who also plan to attend game on. To that end I'm leaving three comments on my post, each with a server name, and please up vote the server your account is on (assuming you have one).

Comment: North America /10char

Comment: EU East /10char

Comment: EU West /10char

Answer (score 6):

**Minecraft: Ultra Hardcore** [Signup thread](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4375/4012)

Everyone spawns in a different place on a naturally generated map, a limited playing area to promote conflict and to stop people spreading out too much.

The server is running this mod: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1008473-123-xxxhardcorexxx-mod/

This means that you can only regenerate health using Golden apples/regeneration potions or heath potions. And everyone can see everyone else's health.

The goal is to be the last one standing.

**Pros:**

- It can be recorded by multiple people to be used on our [YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/GamingSE?feature=g-u-u)
- Any amount of players can play (up to a server limit).
- The map can be be any size to accommodate the number of players.

**Cons:**

- May take a while depending on how many people are playing.

I got this idea from watching the people on the MindCrack server playing the game.

Comment: I was totally going to suggest this, it sounds like so much fun and I don't know anyone who actually plays minecraft for me to play this with.

Answer (score 5):

**[Xonotic](http://www.xonotic.org/)**

This is a free, open-source FPS in the vein of arena shooters like *Quake Live*.

User Review:

> [Xonotic is] an amazing game. Not just cross platform (win, mac,
>   linux) but also completely open source. Normally that would sound like
>   a cheap game with awful graphics, but this is worth checking out if
>   you like the retro fast-paced FPS games like Quake or Unreal
>   Tournament. The graphics are amazing and its easy to pick up and play
>   for beginners.

Comment: I ***really*** like this idea. It looks like it is enjoyable with any number of people, and that people can easily drop in and out while we play.

Comment: I just found out about this today from the Battle for Wesnoth newsletter.

Answer (score 4):

Another game to try would be **[Monday Night Combat](http://store.steampowered.com/app/63200)**.  MNC is also team based, split into two teams (KF has one team).

It also supports 12 players on a server, so it's more than Killing Floor's 6 and less than Team Fortress 2's 24.

The problem with MNC for our purposes is that the server is Windows only.  Which is a surprise since it uses a newer version of the same game engine as Killing Floor, which does have a Linux server.

Comment: I love MNC, don't know why since its a TF2 clone, but then jetpacks are awesome

Answer (score 4):

[**Galcon**](http://www.galcon.com/flash/) (flash version)

Answer (score 4):

[**D.I.P.R.I.P. Warm Up**](http://store.steampowered.com/app/17530/) is a fairly fun arcade-ish car shooter game that's free for anyone who has a Source game (it's a Source Mod).

Comment: Wow, that looks *really* fun.  But tell me it doesn't use the same vehicle controls as Half-Life 2.

Answer (score 4):

If we can get some Dungeon Defenders action going that would be awesome.  Perfect coop style game.

Comment: How may players can you have per game?

Comment: @gnomeslice 4 per game

Answer (score 3):

**[Killing Floor](http://www.killingfloorthegame.com/)** would be a good choice. Team-based, but you don't need to gather as large of a group as you would with TF2.

Comment: Incidentally, I have a KF server already operating at 173.212.246.229:7707, although if you want to add it to Steam, you need to add it as 173.212.246.229:28852

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Team Fortress 2, we could also play the [Prop Hunt mod](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/PropHunt).  I currently have it running on OCReMix RED.

Basically, one team is disguised as objects in the stage, and the other team has to hunt them down.  Once they succeed or time runs out, the teams switch.

Comment: I love prop hunt! Do you have certain props like the Soda Popper turned off, out of curiosity?

Comment: I found this to be funny at first, but quickly became boring for me (of course, it's just my opinion)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to do some **Left 4 Dead 2** at some point.  Either co-op or versus, doesn't matter to me.

Comment: Versus would allow more people to play together, so that may be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Game Suggestion:

- AirMech

**Price:** *free* with optional purchases in game for extra skins, unlocking equipment faster, etc.

**Platforms:**

- [Desura](http://www.desura.com/games/airmech)
- [Standalone Download](http://carbongames.com/download.html)
- [Google Chrome](https://www.carbongames.com/chrome.html)
- [Steam Beta](http://www.alienwarearena.com/giveaway/airmech-closed-beta-key-1000-diamonds/) - Requires a beta key, which you can get in under a minute from Alienware, [here](http://www.alienwarearena.com/giveaway/airmech-closed-beta-key-1000-diamonds/).

There's also a [subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/AirMech/) that I helped out with a little.

Comment: How many players is AirMech?

Comment: @Wipqozn Maximum of eight, currently (4vs4).

Answer (score 1):

**[Diablo 2: LOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_II:_Lord_of_Destruction)**

'Nuff said.

Comment: This is currently scheduled for the start of December, if Diablo 3 comes out by then (lol), perhaps we should play that instead?

Answer (score 1):

If there's one game on this list I *absolutely* think we should play, it's [King Arthur's Gold](http://kag2d.com/en/).

Trailer:

---

This is a team-driven sidescroller which may strike you as similar to Terraria at first.  However, the games are much more structured, and it's **free**(mostly). It's *loads* of fun.

- Imagine TF2 had a baby with Terraria.  That's basically what you get with KAG.  Awesome.
- You can have upwards of 32 players in one game at a time.
- There are (currently) three classes to choose from;  Knights, Archers, and Builders, each with abilities that work well with other classes, but only if played correctly.
- Last time I checked (It's still in development), there was a Capture the Flag mode, deathmatch, and Zombie Fortress (survival) modes of play.
- Building physics allow you to undermine structures to collapse them on top of the enemy.
- Jump in / jump out gameplay.  You can join or leave a game at any time.
- Free!  If you decide to 'buy the game', you get to change the head style of your units, and access to premium servers, but that's pretty much it.
- Supports server hosting.  I don't know if we could use the server space SE has given us to host our own private server for this, but it would be *amazing* if we could, because much of the community isn't very polite, or terribly smart.

One of the great things about KAG is that the areas are completely dynamic; you can build  structures for whatever you need, and dig tunnels just about anywhere.

Comment: ...Not sure why the youtube link won't onebox.

Answer (score 0):

Game Suggestion:

- [Super Spring Break SpeedBoat Hero SD](http://springbreakhero.com/)

To be completely honest (for once!), I actually can't think of a more casual/accessible game than this for *Game on!* sessions.  It's undeniably fun to build tracks, share them with other players, and compare your times.  There was some great fun in chat a little while ago between a few users playing this game.

[Here's](http://springbreakhero.com/?g=7jzl4g) an example of how the 'multiplayer' works, using a custom track of mine.

---

To keep things more organized and competitive, I think it would be great if on SSBSH nights, we had maybe four or five tracks in a given list, and had users race them for times 'grand prix' style.

Comment: I would try this out if I wasn't too lazy to install unity.

Comment: Unity not compatible with Linux.  *dislike*

Answer (score 0):

> **Wipqozn**: There has been a request to play **Day of Defeat** instead of **Day of Defeat: Source** due to a user only owning **Day of Defeat**. In order to determine how many users only own one or the other (and also those who own boths) I've added three comments to this answer. Please up vote the one which describes your situation.

## [Day of Defeat: Source](http://www.dayofdefeat.com/) ($10)

[image]

This is the update Source version of Day of Defeat, which was one of the first of the HL mods developed by a third party to really hit it's stride as a full featured Half Life modification. The game capitalizes on team work which was a breath of fresh air compared to many of the Half Life mods at that time, and to come, which were mainly focused around "Rambo" users. While skilled users can still run around and do their own thing - dominating the top of the kills leaderboard because they have a nice sniper nest - most maps can't be won without coordination of multiple people working as a unit, and the game is designed to reward those who work towards winning the map - not killing the most people. Due to it's early and continued success the Day of Defeat mod team joined Valve back in 2003 and have continued working and improving the game since.

[image]

I've immensely enjoy playing this game, and it's older brother Day of Defeat, for the past 10 years. If enough people were interested in playing out epic skirmishes with maps drawn directly from historical places in World War II, then I believe this could be a great game to feature and enjoy during a Game On!

Comment: I only own Day of Defeat, or would only buy DoD to join this Game On!

Comment: I only own Day of Defeat Source, or would only buy DoD to join this Game On!

Comment: I own both Day of Defeat and Day of Defeat Source, or would buy either to join this Game On!

Comment: I'm on a horse.

Comment: I'm an otter​​​.

Answer (score -1):

**[Neptune's Pride](http://np.ironhelmet.com/)**

I haven't played it yet, but it seems like it would fit our purposes nicely.  It's a strategy game, and it's real time.  As in, your fleet might take *actual* hours to cross the galaxy.  Just log in once a day whenever you get some time, issue your orders, and come back later.

Comment: I used to play this.  It's far *far* too slow-paced to really meet our weekly *Game On!* needs, unfortunately.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Yeah, I wasn't thinking it would be played over the course of a single afternoon, but rather over a week or so in addition to our other game of the week.

Answer (score -2):

I think we could try [BattleField Heroes](http://www.battlefieldheroes.com/).  From what I gather, it's similar to games like Team Fortress, but plays in the browser.

Comment: It's not in a browser, it just launches from it. You have to download the whole game to your hard drive.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Yes, I noticed that when I tried to play it.  Really deserves a downvote though?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, I'm just sayin'...