# Determining the hour that works the best for Game On's

Tags: discussion, game-on

Let's have a "quick" poll to see when the most people are available at any one time for the [Game On](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/reviving-game-on)'s during a **typical weekend**.

#### [<s>Vote and</s> see results](http://www.doodle.com/we852h3gcctg5ux2#table).

It might be easier for you to use [the calendar view](http://www.doodle.com/we852h3gcctg5ux2#calendar) to vote, but do make sure you also look at the following week for the sunday event options!

Comment: Hm, my regular schedule changes every other weekend. Is there any way to account for that?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I dunno. If you have overlaps in both weekends I'd give a 'yes' to those and an 'ifneedsbe' to each weekend's availability. Otherwise just do an OR of your availabilities so that you can at least play every other weekend. Perhaps if more than one time emerges, we can have more than one game on per weekend, but changing the schedule every other week doesn't sound like a good plan.

Comment: The "gap" in each day is imbalanced. I see no slots between the 0400 and 1400 ones on Sat, but the gap is between the 0000 and 0900 ones on Sun (London / UTC+1). Any specific reason why?

Comment: @DMA57361 I made the assumption that saturday nights would be off limits for most of us and thus cut the long tail of Saturday short in an effort to reduce the choices to vote on.

Comment: I know there were a lot of times listed already, it just felt "odd" with gaps. :) And for someone on the US west coast (for example) UTC 0300 Sunday is (I think) 2000 Saturday to them locally - plenty of time for gaming before bed, no? My point being that every possible timeslot is effectively "night" to *someone*...

Comment: I came here to ask the same thing about Saturdays, I guess people still go out, but it's the night I have more availability :P (forever-married-with-children)

Comment: Also, I can extend my time until 4 AM (GMT-3) with no problems, that's how I game now

Comment: Fine; I added a few more options. :)

Comment: I did Week A/Week B for my general availability, this past weekend being A and the 23rd-25th being B, going back to A for the 30th-2nd and so on. That's the typical pattern for my weekends. I'm actually way less available weekends than I am weekdays.

Answer (score 1):

I closed the poll. We have two 'peak' times, both in the US afternoon/EU evening, same time, one Saturday and one Sunday. To make things easier I highlighted them by 'accepting' them, so you can see which is which in your timezone.

I see no problem in aiming for both, to be completely honest. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree that we should aim for both times. Not only will this ensure nearly everyone should be able to attend at a Game On! at least once a week, but for people that can attend both, all the better.

Comment: Sounds good to me... but what TZ are steam events listed as? In the doodle thing above you've highlighted 2000 onwards (for my local time) but I'm seeing 1800 onwards on steam...?

Comment: @DMA57361 Try again

Comment: Whoa O_o it's like some time warping madness