# Frozen Synapse tournament

Tags: discussion, community-event

> It appears we all need to be on the same game server. Please edit your meta post to include your game server so can do some testing and decide on a server.
>   **If this is true, the plan is to play on UK1**
>   [The Bracket is out.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29281634/Frozen%20Synapse%20Tournament%20Bracket.png)
>   An update to the rules has been posted. Please see below.

[image: Bracket]

**When:** The tournament is going on now.

**Who will I be playing?**: The bracket will be updated throughout the tournament

**To Sign up:** To sign up just post an answer in the meta post with your Frozen Synapse username and that you wish to  attend the tournament. **The cut off day for sign ups is Tuesday, October 25th.**  Please be aware that usernames are case-sensitive.

**Game Modes:** See the bracket

**Move Time Limit:** Although there will be no limit on how long a game can take, we currently are aiming on a **move time limit of 3 days**. In other words you would have 3 days (or 72 hours) to make a move. If you don't make your move you forfeit the match.

**What do I do if a player hasn't made their move within 3 days?:** Make a post in chat, and ping @GnomeSlice and @Wipqozn.

**Bracket Structure:**

- The tournament will be **Double Elimination**.
- The results of each match will be determined by the **best two out of three** games.

**Chat:** We will be using [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1558/frozen-synapse-tournament) chat room throughout the tournament as one of our main forms of communication.

<s>**Record Your Games:** Since Frozen Synapse has a built in feature to upload all matches to youtube, we request that you upload your matches to Youtube when you finish them. This way the matches can be shared amongst the community.</s>

> It seems this feature is broken.  If you wish to record your games with fraps or a similar program, that would be great. However note this is 100% optional. Do not concern yourself with this if you don't want to bother.

**What do I do after a match?:** After you've finished a match please make a post in the chat with the results, and ping both @GnomeSlice and @Wipqozn.

**Questions? Complaints? Suggestions?**

Comment: I'll sign-up as soon as I can put SpaceChem away long enough to install Frozen Synapse.

Comment: I've a few questions about game modes (can we drop hostage? The teams have different roles, and while this is true of other modes in those you get to bid for your role, so hostage is potentially less balanced that the others imo. And light/dark?), how levels will be selected (predetermined seeds / random, what about the rare unit-stuck-in-a-box issue?), and I assume looking at win/loss only, with no regard for the score given by the game? These are just relatively minor implementation details, that I assume will be covered by the more details to be provided later, but thought I'd ask early.

Comment: @DMA57361 There is still some discussion whether we ant to include Light games in the first round (I want all dark, but Gnomeslice would like light games for the first round)

Comment: @DMA57361 IT will be based purely on win/loss

Comment: @DMA57361 You make a good point about hostage. Let's see what others users think about this as well so we can make a decision.

Comment: @DMA57361 There are currently two methods we are considering for level selection, which one we use will depend on how many players we get. We want to play each game mode once, so we'll be designing the level selection around that. I will make a point to say we are not considering a random seed.

Comment: Argh! O_o Comment flood! If it matters (I assume that it doesn't, but oh well) you can add my vote to the "all dark" camp.

Comment: @DMA57361 haha yeah, just thought it would be easier to read if I answered each of your questions in its own comment. Also, I'll add your vote to all the all dark camp. Also, your vote matters in the sense that the more people who say all dark the easier it will be for me convince Gnomeslice to join that camp as well :)

Comment: I was thinking we'd play different game types in each level of the tournament.  I doubt we're going to have many levels, based on the number of people, so I was thinking elimination, charge, and something else.

Comment: We need to talk about game servers. I've played all my games on TEXAS3, and I can confirm that if the player you're looking for has never played a game on the server you're using, their username will be unable to be found. Is there an 'official' server for gaming.SE, or will we arrange on a match-by-match basis?

Comment: @jsnlxndlv I was unaware this was a problem. THank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: This isn't true, I was able to add you @jsnlxndrlv, we just didn't have 100% confirmation from you that it was your username.

Comment: What software was used to make the chart?

Comment: @gnomeslice is the one who made it, he is the person to ask.

Comment: Adobe Photoshop CS5.

Comment: @GnomeSlice; Thanks; I was hoping you wouldn’t say that. I was hoping it was specific graphing software. `:-(`

Comment: I'm sure there IS software you can use to do this.  If you just need to set up a tournament bracket, check out [printyourbrackets.com](http://www.printyourbrackets.com/).  This is where I went first before making it pretty in Photoshop.  I didn't actually print one from there, just figured out how many players I had, and what kind of tournament it was.

Comment: Well now that I *have* this game, when's the next one?  :D

Answer (score 2):

We really need to actually knuckle down and *finish* this thing.  It's getting a bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in.  My username is *GnomeSlice*.

---

Depending on how busy people end up being, the time limit for making a move may have to be flexed a little.  We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

THis may come as a surprise, but I'm in as well.

Username: wipqozn.

Comment: I'll assume someone up voted this because I'm as handsome as I am awesome.

Comment: "Player Wipqozn not found"

Answer (score 0):

Count me in.

**FS username:** DMA57361

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm on.  My username is bwarner.

Comment: Just pinging you so you know the bracket has been posted

Comment: Your next match is *finally* ready! You'll be racing ArdaXi

Answer (score 0):

Signing up!

Username: **Adversity**

Comment: Just pinging you so you know the bracket has been posted

Answer (score 0):

me!!!me!!!me!!!

Username: ProSay

It's case-sensitive.

Comment: Frozen Synapse says this username doesn't exist.  Sure you got the right one?

Comment: "Player Prosay not found"

Comment: Ah, your name needs a capital S as well.  I've fixed your post for you.

Comment: Just pinging you so you know the bracket has been posted

Comment: i have already played the first match with nanor

Answer (score 0):

Might as well.

Username: **Nanor**

Answer (score 0):

**I'm user jsnlxndrlv on server TEXAS3.**

In. [This](http://steamcommunity.com/id/jasonlove) is my Steam profile; you should be able to add me with jasonlove or jsnlxndrlv, but I haven't actually tested to verify that this is correct.

Comment: Frozen Synapse doesn't use your steam account, you should have made up an account for it the first time you started it.

Comment: @jsnlxndrlv We need your *Frozen Synapse* username, not your Steam name.

Comment: I added "jsnlxndrlv", did that work?

Comment: @jsnlxndrlv If I don't get confirmation of your FS username by the end of today, I won't be able to enter you in the bracket.

Comment: I'm at work at the moment so I can't log in, but [Youtube seems to indicate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCqfNJOyCMg) that 'jsnlxndrlv' is correct.

Comment: Alright, I can confirm that 'jsnlxndrlv' is my FS username. I've been playing on Texas-3 but it's not like I can't just switch wherever.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I suppose I was foolish to assume that "the end of today" would refer to an American timezone, but unless there were timestamps quoted that I now cannot find, I was under the impression that I'd satisfied your criteria for inclusion in the tournament. Was I mistaken?

Comment: @jsnlxndrlv There was a cutoff time posted in the main post of this thread.  Sorry, but you've missed it.  =[  Nothing I could do.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Sorry, I guess I'm just confused. I stated my intent to participate over ten days ago and confirmed that I *had* a username, and in fact even posted it. While it's true I had my Steam username and Frozen Synapse name mixed up, I wasn't aware that this ambiguity could prevent me from participating. Your statement to the contrary, your declaration of a cutoff time [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/3025/8), and the subsequent *arrival* of that cutoff time all occurred in less than 24 hours. Why make an exception for Joseph but not for me?

Comment: @jsnlx Joseph showed up mere minutes after the cutoff time, before I'd actually started the bracket, so I could still accommodate him.  And yes, you posted with some usernames, but there was no way to be sure that one of them was you, as you said yourself you hadn't tested.  However, I do feel bad about this, and you're welcome to take my place in the tournament if you like.

Comment: Nah, that's okay. Please keep your spot—but I WILL be taking vengeance for this slight in-game against all of you!

Answer (score 0):

### ArdaXi

Answer (score 0):

_bp is me.

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly no experience with Frozen Synapse, but I'll join the tournament anyways. (**Pewqazz**)

Comment: Just pinging you so you know the bracket has been posted

Answer (score 0):

I'll give this a shot even though I'm anticipating losing horribly.

Username: FallenAngelEyes

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good.

My username is: **jaminja**

Comment: Just pinging you so you know the bracket has been posted