# Ultra-hardcore signups

Tags: discussion, game-on

**Submissions are CLOSED for the both days and are now being posted on youtube.**

**Please answer this thread with the following:**

- **Your Minecraft username**
- **The days you can play**
- **Whether you can record**
- **A picture representing you or description of  a picture for the recording of the event (see the player's pictures in the Mindcrack intro below for examples).**

One the 1st and 8th of April at 1800UTC (Events for the 1st: [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/stackgaming/events/921224994964609058) [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/events/198860513549892/). Events for the 8th [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/stackgaming/events/921224994964686592) [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/events/301196993286719/)) we will be playing a game of Minecraft called Ultra-hardcore the objective of this game is stay alive the longest using any means necessary (other than hacking).

The game has been altered so that you will not regain health from being at full hunger, so health potions and golden apples must be used. However, their recipes have been altered so that it requires 8 gold *ingots* for a golden apple and a gold *block* for the glistering melon (for the heath potion).

You can also see every other player's health along with their name and connection strength.

We are aiming to have as many recordings of this game as possible, so if you are able to record, please say so.

You need [this client mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1008473-124-xxxhardcorexxx-mod/) to play.

This game was invented by MindCrack, so you may watch it before playing.

Comment: Do players need to be available for both sessions?

Comment: @fredley No, you can go to as many or as little as you like.

Comment: looks fun, but don't have Minecraft

Comment: @Blem A minor inconvenience.

Comment: Are the recordings going to be compiled together? If so, we should agree on using the same texture pack (probably default.) Also, what are the rules on F3, brightness settings, alliances, and branch mining? What about client-side mods, like Zombe's Wield or Info?

Comment: @Dan All recordings will be kept as their own series, F3 is allowed, branch mining isn't and no client side mods (apart from visual ones and the hardcore one).

Comment: Are you running the server? If so, can you allow nicknames via something like Essentials, so we can use a name other than our official Minecraft usernames (like our G.SE names)?

Comment: @Dan The mod is not compatible with bukkit, so if you would like this please suggest a mod that works with vanilla.

Comment: My advice is that you should create a minecraft.jar file that has the mod in it, and no other mods, then upload it to like mediafire or something, and everyone just downloads and uses that .jar.

That way, you know no-one's using any mods to cheat, and no-one should have issues getting in game etc.

Comment: @MrSmooth It's against the [EULA for Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/terms) to distribute the original or a modified version of the binary.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I see, I just assumed it was allowed since that's what the Mindcrack guys did.

Comment: When exactly are we playing? Facebook says 7pm, and Steam says 1pm. I think Steam is correct (since that's UTC 1800 for me) but is there any way to make Facebook take time zones into account?

Comment: Also, what is the server info? Or will we be informed of that tomorrow?

Comment: @DanRasmussen Steam is correct, go to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/271/se-game-on at around 1730UTC and we'll explain what's happening.

Comment: Just letting you know I'm no longer available on the 8th (I edited my answer but figured I should comment to make sure you see it). Have fun everyone who plays.

Answer (score 2):

- Minecraft UN: Fredy31
- Recording : April 1st
- Picture: I'll try something out.

We could do something like camera changes for the video. I have some ideas.

And I have an idea for the viewer UI
[image]

Comment: Yay, I am famous!

Comment: +1 for making Wipqozn dead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in - playing ALL the days!

- Minecraft username: thepugs
- Recording: possibly...
- Picture: TBD

Answer (score 0):

For no apparent reason, I feel the need to say I will also be playing on both days.

- Minecraft username: Nanor
- Recording: On both days
- Picture: I will be asking Ronan to draw me something.

Answer (score 0):

I plan on playing the first day, and any other time that isn't Easter..

- Minecraft username: cyclotis04
- Recording: Hopefully
- Picture: TBD (by Ronan)

Answer (score 0):

Every day possible.

- Minecraft username: OrigamiRobot
- Recording: Maybe
- Picture: RonanForman can draw me something :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm anticipating dying horribly and quickly, but I plan on playing any days I can.  My schedule is rather unpredictable, so I don't know how often that will be.

- Minecraft username: Musicman93
- Recording: Nope.
- Picture: How illegal would it be if I stole a frame from the end fight scene of [Revenge](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPJUBQd-PNM)?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Every single day.</strike> I can no longer make the 8th, but I had a great time on the 1st, and I'd love to do it again some time. Have fun guys.

- Minecraft username: Mr_Smooth
- Recording: For sure.
- Picture: If someone could draw [Deadpool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool) wearing a suit, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and acknowledge my interest in playing on both days, but am currently unsure as to whether or not I will actually be able to do so. But, just in case I *can*:

- **Minecraft username:** nihilistronin
- **Recording:** Quite possible
- **Picture:** I have faith in the drawing capabilities of RonanForman

Answer (score 0):

- **Minecraft username:** TheRedX
- **The days you can play:** 8th
- **Recording:** No recording for me. (I'm sure everyone else can record my failures sufficiently)
- **Picture:** May I request that Ronan draw something? **Suggestion:** Just something with me standing there wielding a diamond sword and looking awesome.

Comment: We probably won't be taking using any void as we don't want to give to much away to each other. And I can't draw anything if you don't give me a suggestion

Comment: @RonanForman Alright, thanks for telling me. I also appended a general suggestion for you.

Comment: @RonanForman Looks like my computer won't be able to handle any recording, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am in, both days

- Minecraft username: Crysyn
- Recording: I need to free up my HDD space to record for That long
- Picture: Dunno, maybe just snap a screenie of my [skin in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcYCi.png) and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm good to play on the 8th, probably.

- Username: GnomeSlice
- Recording: No, not until I get a better tool.
- Picture: Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Bought the game

- Minecraft username: Blemx
- The days you can play: any day :)
- Recording: Not sure, have to see if i got room on a hdd, but i should be able to stream
- Picture: Don't have any :(

Comment: I wouldn't stream, it'd probably give away your position.

Comment: So you are saying someone is so low that they would cheat?

Comment: I know _I_ would, if I wasn't recording.

Answer (score -1):

- Username: Nosedrool
- Days: Both
- Recording: No
- Picture: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbUhP.jpg)

Comment: To save space so signups can be read through more quickly, I changed the image embed into a link.