# How can we bring new life to Arqade's Steam Community Group?

Tags: discussion, community

Let's face it: [Arqade's Steam Group](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/arqadecommunity) is pretty much dead at the moment. No events, no announcements (with the exception of the recent phishing scam warning from badp), right now it's just another place where we can see our avatars together. We're gamers, and we're a community, it shouldn't be that hard to find some games we could play together, right? And we could use this opportunity to promote Arqade itself, maybe with promotions, or events to let the group grow and introduce newcomers to this community.

There's a great potential here, that right now is going wasted.

So, what do you think? Could this be a good thing? If you think so, any ideas to make it work?

Comment: Remember when we were actively using the group and then Nick T complained about the spam and people upvoted him? Yeah, that's what happened pretty much.

Comment: @badp no, I don't remember it because I wasn't around at the time. Do you have a link to that discussion? I'm just trying to propose something to do with a group that, at the moment, has no purpose at all.

Comment: @badp Where did that scam topic go? I can't find it.

Comment: @Decency I deleted it as the reports stopped coming.

Comment: @Kappei This is the question http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/steam-events-need-to-be-more-descriptive I agree it isn't quite as I remembered it, but it was bad enough for me that it made me stop make events on Steam to begin with.

Comment: @badp thanks for the link. Well, it seems there's not much interest in reviving the group... At least I tried.

Answer (score 2):

Let me propose something myself:

- **Use the Group's chat**. I know that The Bridge satisfies any chatting needs of this community, but while playing Steam's chat can be a good way to keep in touch. It can also be good to interact with people from the outside.
- **Set up a trading thread**. Putting a sticky trading thread on the group's forum can give it a lot more visibility than [a thread on this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3536/23609).
- **Gaming events**. There's a [community TF2 server](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/community-team-fortress-2-server) (is it still alive?), why not make a good use of it? Also there are many games that can be played coop and require no server, we just need a little cooperation.
- **Giveaways**. [SteamGifts](http://www.steamgifts.com/) can be a good place to make some gifts for the group, but also to promote Arqade, recruiting new people and showing them how awesome we are :)

And for now that's all, I'll try to come up with something else later.

Comment: I'm not sure about the group chat thing because it could lead to group fragmentation. Any conversation is going to take place either on the Bridge or in the group chat, and it would be hard/weird to participate in both. Besides that, I like it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I know that the chat may be a problem, but it can also be useful: Steam interface can be brought up at any time in-game, and it's faster than Alt+Tab. Also you get notifications if somebody tries to contact you while playing.

Comment: Yeah, -1 to the steam chart idea.